# iterating over list-valued dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary that has tuplets as keys and lists of tuples as values, for example:

```
d={(0,1):[(1,1)],
   (0,2):[(1,1),(1,2)],
   (0,3):[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]}
```

I would like to remove all entries such that their value is contained in the value of another key, for example:

from d I would like to remove the entry with key (0,1) because the (1,1) is contained in [(1,1),(1,2)]
and remove the entry with key (0,2) because [(1,1),(1,2)] is contained in [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)].
Order of tuples in the lists matters.

I can solve this using a bunch of for loops, like this:

```
for key, val in d.items():
    for k,v in d.items():
        for i in range(0, len(val)):
            if val[i] in v and len(v) - len(val) == 1:
                del_me = True
            else:
                del_me = False
                break
        if del_me:
             to_del.append(key)
for key in set(to_del):
    del d[key]
```

edit: (further explanation)
Keys are not important here but will be important later.
In other words:
let a,b,c,d denote unique tuples
let k1,k2,..., denote keys

lets have the entries:

```
k1:[a],
k2:[d],
k3:[a,b],
k4:[b,a],
k5:[a,b,c],
```

I want to end up with:
k2,k4,k5

Removed entries will be:
k1 because a is in k3
k3 because a,b is in k5

It hurts my eyes when I'm looking at this, sorry.

What would be a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: For-loops *are pythonic*. It's still not entirely clear to me exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Keys have ordered lists of tuples as values. The values for different keys may be created by appending more tuples to a list which is already a value of another key. Then I want to remove that previous key with shorter list.

Comment: in other words: I add another entry. The value was constructed by appending some new pairs to the value of already existing entry. I want to remove that already existing entry. I want to keep only the entries with longest sequences not contained in another entry sequences. Is that clear now?

Comment: Will the sequence of dictionary always remain the same? I mean in the end will you always get the dictionary with only one key value pair? @4rk

Comment: there will be more than one key value pair with unique sequence in value; i mean in the end i want to end up with one key value pair per unique sequence of tuples

Comment: What are you trying to figure out? This is a pythonic script as far as I'm aware...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you have an `dictionary` that looks like as follows:

```
d={(0,1):[(1,1)],(0,2):[(1,1),(1,2)],(0,3):[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],(0,4):[(1,1),(1,2),(1,4)]}
```

Now you want to compare the `values` against all the `keys` with one another. I suggest you place all the values in this dictionary in a `list`.

```
mylist=[]
for key in d.keys():
    mylist.append(d[key])
    
print(mylist)
```

`mylist` will look like as follows having all the values of the dictionary.

```
[[(1, 1)], [(1, 1), (1, 2)], [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4)]]
```

Now you want to compare all these values with one another and remove those values that are the `subsets` of any of those values. Like in this example, `[(1,1)]` is the subset of `[(1,1),(1,2)]` and so `[(1,1)]` will be removed. Similarly,  `[(1,1),(1,2)]` is the subset of `[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]` and so it will also be removed. We can accomplish this as follows:

```
out = [] 

for k, elm in enumerate(mylist):  
    for _,elm2 in enumerate(mylist[:k] + mylist[k + 1:]):  
        if frozenset(elm).issubset(elm2):  
            break  
    else:  
        out.append(elm)    

print(out)
```

`out` list will give us unique elements of the list `mylist`.

```
[[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4)]]
```

In the above segment of code, we loop over the list and take the current index. Then we loop again over the same list but we remove the element at the current index of the first loop. Then we convert the first element of the index of the first loop into a `frozenset` and use the method `issubset` in order to check if the first element if a subset of the second element or not.

Now we just compare our dictionary `d` values with `out` list. And if, `d` values are not in `out` list we delete that `key` from the dictionary `d`. This is accomplished as follows:

```
for key in list(d):
    if d[key] not in out:
        del d[key]
        
print(d)
```

Th `output` dictionary `d` will be:

```
{(0, 3): [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], (0, 4): [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4)]}
```

Comment: what happens if 2 values are the same?

Comment: They will be removed too, since they are not unique values.